# Как форматировать код в вопросах и ответах?

Tags: поддержка, faq, форматирование, блок-кода

Каким образом нужно оформлять текст сообщения, чтобы он был отформатирован как код?

Что нужно сделать, чтобы при публикации код отображался надлежащим образом, то есть не был экранировал или удален? И как получить правильную подсветку синтаксиса?

> Дополнительную информацию см. в разделе «[Как форматировать сообщения с помощью Markdown или HTML?](/help/formatting)» в [Справке](/help).

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса «[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)»</sub>

Answer (score 13):

### Встроенный код (без разрывов строки)

- Если курсор установлен в любой позиции, кроме первой, или вы выделили текст, не содержащий разрывов строки, используйте кнопку выделения кода редактора `{}` (см. рисунок ниже).
- Заключите код в обратные кавычки: `` `<html>` ``.
- Заключите код в тег `<code>` и вручную выполните необходимые преобразования HTML-сущностей: `<code>&lt;html&gt;</code>`.
- Выделите часть текста и нажмите клавиши <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> или <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> для OS X) или нажмите кнопку выделения кода редактора `{}` (см. рисунок ниже).

### Блоки кода (с сохранением разрывов строки)

- Если курсор установлен в начало строки или вы выделили текст, содержащий разрывы строки, используйте кнопку выделения кода редактора `{}` (см. рисунок ниже).
- Вставьте код, выделите все строки и нажмите клавиши <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> или <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> для OS X).
- Добавьте четыре (4) пробела для отступа в начале каждой строки.
- Заключите код в теги `<pre>` или `<pre><code>` (именно в таком порядке; [последовательность `<code><pre>` недопустима](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128477/display-error-when-nesting-pre-in-code-elements/128480#128480)) и самостоятельно выполните необходимые преобразования HTML-сущностей (например, `&lt;` для `<`).

Часто код, который вы вставляете из IDE, содержит символы табуляции. При обработке сообщения символы табуляции заменяются на пробелы. Несмотря на это, следует удалять символы табуляции из вставляемого кода, на случай если другим участникам потребуется применять дополнительное форматирование.

[image: code blocking icon properly highlighted]

### Код внутри цитаты

Для каждого уровня вложенности нужно добавить отступ с помощью дополнительных четырех пробелов.

```
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

>   for(;;)
        echo 'badger ';
```

### Код внутри списка

Для каждого уровня вложенности нужно добавить отступ с помощью дополнительных четырех пробелов.

```
- Первый элемент (самый глубокий)

        for(;;)
        echo 'ow ';

- Второй элемент
```

### Подсветка синтаксиса

Для подсветки синтаксиса используется библиотека [Prettify](//code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), но она работает, [только если](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72391/why-isnt-syntax-highlighting-working-in-a-question) язык удается однозначно определить по меткам в вопросе или если вы вручную добавите подсказки в HTML-комментарии следующим образом:

```
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    строки кода

<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    строки кода
```

Также можно задать синтаксис для *всех* блоков кода в сообщении, используя для этого подсказку `language-all`:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-or-tag-here -->

    строки кода

Дополнительный текст, не входящий в блоки кода

    строки кода
```

См. [полную спецификацию](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) и [список языковых подсказок](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109).

Необходимо помнить, что:

- Комментарии в HTML *нельзя* выделять отступами.
- *Необходимо* добавлять пустую строку между `<!-- language: ... -->` и блоком кода с отступом.
- Необходимо добавлять пробел между `language:` и обозначением языка.
- При использовании тега для указания языка помните, что название тега необходимо вводить *с учетом регистра*.

Если язык не определен, то подсветка синтаксиса вообще не используется. Несмотря на это, в определенных случаях — в режиме предварительного просмотра или в когда несколько меток указывают на сильно различающиеся языки, но при этом язык не указан вручную, — используется подсветка по умолчанию, при которой функция Prettify выбирает наиболее подходящий вариант подсветки.

После завершения редактирования исходного текста в Markdown применение подсветки текста в режиме предварительного просмотра происходит с задержкой около 5 секунд.

### Код на мобильных устройствах

- Чтобы получить обратную кавычку, в некоторых случаях нужно [нажать и удерживать](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133673/is-there-a-way-to-enter-back-tick-backtick-on-so-when-using-ipad-or-iphone) кнопку обычной одинарной кавычки.

### Обратные кавычки в тексте

- Чтобы добавить символ обратной кавычки, при этом не начав случайно набирать встроенный код, экранируйте символ обратной кавычки: `` \` ``

  - `` like \` so `` превращается в like ` so
  - `` <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>\`</kbd> gets `|` `` превращается в: <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> gets `|`

### Обратные кавычки внутри обратных кавычек

- Для добавления символов обратной кавычки внутри блока кода [используйте любое *уникальное* количество обратных кавычек](//daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code) в качестве открывающего и закрывающего разделителей: как ``` ``literal backtick (`) here`` ```, так и, например, ``````` ``````literal backtick (`) here`````` ``````` превращаются в `` literal backtick (`) here ``. Эта функция [также работает и в комментариях](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oAaC.png).
- Для использования добавления символов обратной кавычки в начале и/или в конце последовательности символов добавьте по *одному* пробелу к открывающему и к закрывающему разделителям:  ``` `` `<html>` `` ``` превращается в `` `<html>` ``, а ``` `` $` `` ``` превращается в оператор языка Perl `` $` ``. Добавление дополнительного пробела к разделителям не поддерживается в комментариях. В таком случае экранируйте обратную кавычку: ``` `\`<html>\`` ``` и ``` `$\`` ```, чтобы получить `` `<html>` `` или `` $` `` [в комментарии](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msVOx.png).

Comment: Откуда такой скриншот? Сейчас другие иконки.

Comment: @Qwertiy Из вопроса на английском языке. Буду крайне благодарен вам за новый!

Comment: Про цитаты неверно - в первой строке должно быть 5 пробелов, а не 3. Во второй 8 дадут отступ в 4. У аналогичного кода для списка тогда надо ставить 12, а не 8. А лучше вообще выбрать код, который не требует дополнительного отступа во второй строке.

Comment: @Qwertiy пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь вносить правки! FAQ–вопросы принадлежат сообществу!

Comment: Есть где-то список обозначений языков, которые можно вставлять в <!-- language: ... --> ?

Comment: @V-Mor Если я верно понимаю, то [по ссылке](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/274323) из вопроса есть список поддерживаемых языков.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Большое спасибо